# Generate a list of expression literals from an integer sequence

Tags: r, plot, expression

I would like to map a sequence of integers to a sequence of expression literals in order to use the latter as tick mark labels in a plot, e.g.

```
lbls <- lapply(-2:2, function(i) expression(i * pi))
plot(...)
axis(1, at=seq(-2,2)*pi, labels=lbls)
```

So far I've tried all variations of `bquote`, `substitute`, `expression` etc. that I could think of, but apparently I must have missed something.
Also, the FAQ and related SO questions & answers didn't fully solve this for me.

How would I do it correctly (I want `axis` to render `pi` as the greek letter and have `-2` ... `2` substituted for `i` in the above example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
lbls <- do.call("expression", lapply(-2:2, function(i) substitute(X * pi, list(X = i))))
plot(-10:10, -10:10, xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=seq(-2,2)*pi, labels=lbls)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Roman or, using `bquote` you can write like this: `lbls <- do.call("expression", lapply(-2:2, function(i) bquote(.(i) * pi)))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
lbls <- parse(text = paste(seq(-2, 2), "pi", sep = "*"))
```

Comment: Nice one! I must have overlooked the `text` parameter in `?parse`.

Comment: This suggestion is more helpful for those whose expressions are quite different in the list. Thanks!