# Plotting axis labels with Greek symbols from a vector

Tags: r, plot, label, symbols

I am struggling trying to plot Greek symbols as axis labels. Due to for looping several plots with different scales, I would like to use a vector that contains the symbol name instead of using the symbol name within `expression()`, which works fine:

```
x <- rnorm(10, 5,6)
y <- rnorm(10, 2,1)
xlab <- expression(paste(mu, "mol/mol"))
plot(x,y, xlab = xlab)
```

For some reason, I can't replace "mu" with a vector containing the symbol name:

```
k <- "mu"
xlab <- expression(paste(get(k), "mol/mol"))
plot(x,y, xlab = xlab)
```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973898/combining-paste-and-expression-functions-in-plot-labels), but what worked for functions does not seem to work for Greek symbols:

```
ylab <- substitute(paste(nn, "mol/mol"), list(nn=k))
xlab <- bquote(.(k) * "mol/mol")

plot(x,y, ylab = ylab, xlab = xlab)
```

What do I do wrong? How to get a Greek symbol to axis label through a vector?

Comment: expression is a primitive function. It does not evaluate its arguments.

Comment: Does [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042258/generate-a-list-of-expression-literals-from-an-integer-sequence) help?

Comment: @fotNelton: This wouldn't work at least: ylab <- do.call("expression", lapply(k, function(i) substitute(k * "mol/mol", list(k = i))))

Comment: note that the problem really comes from the fact that `k = "mu"` is a character string that you want interpreted as an expression. If you had `k = quote(mu)`, then `xlab = bquote(.(k)*mol/mol)` works just fine.

Comment: @Largh: There might be a slight misunderstanding. I meant to point you at the use of `parse`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
xlab = parse(text=paste(k, "*mol/mol"))
```

Comment: Can someone explain why the `*` is necessary and what it does?

Comment: `?plotmath` suggests that it is used in `x*y` to "juxtapose x and y", that is to put them one after the other (with no space).

Comment: `~` would add space, in case you wanted that