# Superscript in mtext with variable

Tags: r

I want include a variable in mtext as well as superscript some text:

My ideal output is

```
y.label ADC (10^-6 mm^2/s)
```

where y.label is the value of a variable, **-6** is superscripted and **2** is superscripted

The most promising approach so far is:

```
mtext(expression(paste(y.label, " ADC (", 10^-6, " ", mm^2, "/s)")), side=2, line=2.5, cex=1.2, font=1)
```

This almost works but outputs "y.label" instead of the value of y.label

Grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
y.label <- 1
plot(1:10,1:10, type = "n", ylab = "")
gaa <- parse(text=paste(y.label, "*~ADC(10^-6*~mm^2/s)"))
mtext(gaa, side=2, line=2.5, cex=1.2, font=1)
```

[image]

For explanation see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615334/plotting-axis-labels-with-greek-symbols-from-a-vector)

**EDIT** parse freaks out because of the % sign. You could use [substitute](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substitute.html) instead. Here you have to pass `y.label` into the function through a list/environment. See the help sheet.

```
y.label <- "PVP 10%"
gaa <- substitute(paste(N, " ADC (", 10^-6, " ", mm^2, "/s)"), list(N=y.label))
plot(1:10,1:10, type = "n", ylab = "")
mtext(gaa, side=2, line=2.5, cex=1.2, font=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Almost there: I am using this in a loop and one of the values of y.label is the string **"PVP 10%"**. For some reason, that string triggers an error: `unexpected numeric constant`. I'll keep at it but please let me know if you have any ideas why. Your explanation link is fantastic BTW.