# How do I plot greek letters and evaluated variables together?

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to get the following plot:

```
plot(rnorm(10),main=expression(lambda==10))
```

[image: greek]

However, the number "10" in the title would come from a variable to be evaluated, say `foo`:

```
foo <- 10
```

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4973898/452096) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10615334/452096), but I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: This works for me: `foo <- 10; plot(rnorm(10), main = bquote(lambda==.(foo)))`

Comment: @zx8754: cool, thanks! I did try `bquote`, but only wrapped it around `foo`, then `paste`d it together with `lambda==`... If you'll post this as an answer, I'll happily upvote and accept.

Comment: Happy it worked. In future, note that it is a good practice to show what you have tried in the post.